# making mousekeys settings permanent

Tags: xkb

I figured out how to configure mousekeys with xkb and [xkbset](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xkbset.1.html) use the command command `xkbset ma 300 3 1000 1 6000`. However, the settings don't persist when I reboot. How can I make these settings permanent?

I know there are some similar threads, but I didn't understand them well enough to use them for my question. Thanks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504158/permanently-change-xkb-keybindings has a step-by-step example in the use of setxkbmap

Comment: Thank you for info. I read the page you linked to, and I looked in /usr/share/X11/xkb/ , and I could not find where the settings I'm interested in are stored. There a ./compat/mousekeys , but this does not appear to contain timing settings or any numbers large enough that they could be timing settings.

Comment: Please forgive me asking, but "I can't see where settings are stored" is different from "It didn't work". Did you try the steps in that example, and if so, were the changes you defined persistent?

Comment: I forgive you. ;)

I tried to follow the example, but xkbset doesn't seem to work the same way as setxkbmap. It doesn't have a -print option, and as far I can tell from looking at the files, it doesn't seem to store settings in the same place.