# xkbset setting does not persist

Tags: command-line, accessibility, xkb

I use keys on my keyboard for mouse clicks. For this to work I need to invoke

```
xkbset m
```

This works for a few minutes, then for some reason this setting gets reverted! I have resorted to leaving a terminal open with

```
while true; do xkbset m; sleep 5; done
```

I'm wondering if there's a "correct" way to do this, such that this setting becomes permanent / persistent.

([Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1214822/18623) but with no answer.)

Comment: This may be unrelated, but https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1727469 is a weird way that Firefox can revert keyboard settings, so test that out if you're a Firefox user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to `xkbset` expiry option being set for mouse keys.

You can verify with `q` (query):

```
$ xkbset q exp
...
Upon Expiry Mouse-Keys will be: Off
...
```

Solution: Disable the expiry for mouse keys by doing

```
xkbset exp "=mousekeys"
```

Check new setting:

```
$ xkbset q exp
...
Upon Expiry Mouse-Keys will be: Unchanged
...
```

Then activate them again with

```
$ xkbset m
```

Now the setting should "persist".

(Found the answer [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254660).)